# Path integral presentation of solutions of Dirac equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, smooth-manifolds, stochastic-differential-equations, dirac-operator

It is well known how to present solutions on the heat equation using the path integral (including the case of Riemannian manifold).

**Is there a way to present solutions of the Dirac equation using path integral?**

Here I assume that there is a distinguished time coordinate orthogonal to spatial coordinates. If necessary one may assume that the metric is Riemannian (rather than Minkowskian).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several relevant papers:

- [Path Integral Approach to Relativistic Quantum Mechanics: Two-Dimensional Dirac Equation](https://academic.oup.com/ptps/article/doi/10.1143/PTPS.92.144/1934972) (1987)
- [Path Integral for
  Relativistic Equations of Motion](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9708121) (1997)
- [Path Integral for the
  Dirac Equation](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9809115) (1998)
- [On the Feynman Path Integral for the Dirac Equation in the General Dimensional Spacetime](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-014-1997-x) (2014)
- [On the construction of the Feynman path integral for the Dirac equation](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-construction-of-the-Feynman-path-integral-Ichinose/8e6e88a8f9004d7e394825ea68fa802166533a4d) (2017)